# What is the maximum USB flash-drive's capacity if I want to fully install Ubuntu on it. Is any limitation?

Tags: system-installation

I would like to install Ubuntu on a flash drive/flash memory/tumb drive. I want to know if I just can install in any flash drive as long as the capacity is enough. Mean, the installation is limited by the minimum size, not by the maximum.

Comment: There are limits either way, for example, ext4 has file size and filesystem size limits: https://kernelnewbies.org/Ext4#Bigger_filesystem.2Ffile_sizes.

Comment: I did this few days ago :) I chose XFCE to have a lighter system and I installed on a 12 GB partition on a USB drive (I kept a 4 GB Fat32 partition to be still able to exchange files), and it works fine. But not much extra space indeed, it's more for testing purpose because you are limited in what you can store and what you can install on such a small partition. Also please note that it is not recommended to do so; a full install involves a lot of write operations, which results in altering USB drive faster.

Comment: I agree with you that the file system limits the maximum capacity it can handle. But in this case, it is still far from reaching the maximum limit.

Comment: @flot, have you tried to install on a flash drive? In your installation, what was file system you use?

Comment: @AirCraftLover the 12 GB partition is EXT4.And this is a USB stick so typically a flash drive.

Comment: @FloT, thank you Brother. I will come back to you if I get problem.

Comment: @AirCraftLover sure don't hesitate!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Maximum USB Flash-Drive's Capacity

You can use as large a Flash drive as you can find.

I am running a Full install on a 128GB Lexar, My Ubuntu / partition is 26GB and the rest is NTFS Storage, so windows can read it also.

I have been using this drive as a Full install and Data USB for three years now so I know the size of the Ubuntu partition suits me.

You can increase the size of the OS partition as you see fit, If you have lots of programs or need a large home directory.

Comment: I will try to install and I will comeback if I face problem.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, as long as your drive is large enough to contain the installation, you can. What I've used was two USBs, one with a live install to install onto the other. I'm sure there's a better way but that method is what's generally used.

Comment: Can you tell me what is the size you are using for the full install? Just want to know.

Comment: 16. Not ideal. You can get away with 8GB for a live USB but if you want to run Linux on USB I'd aim 32+, even higher with how cheap they are nowadays.

Comment: I actually asking full installation, not live-USB. Full installation mean, I can save, install application, shutdown and start, and so on. Just like normally we do to our OS.

Comment: A minimal/regular install of Ubuntu is under 20GB, but then you need space to download updates and random dependencies. I have 32GB for very light usage/bug fixing my main system. For comfortable usage, I would get at least 128GB as USBs are cheaper nowadays (with USB3.0 or higher). This gives you space to compile/install packages comfortably. For max size I think you'll be limited by your specific hardware, since ext4 max volume size = ~1 million TB. You should be fine with booting from a 1TB USB if you really need that much space.